# Document.write clears page

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Why in the code below upon the call of `document.write` in the function `validator()` the form elements (the checkbox and button) are removed from screen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validator() {
                if (document.myForm.thebox.checked)
                    document.write("checkBox is checked");
                else 
                    document.write("checkBox is NOT checked");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myForm">
            <input type="checkbox" name ="thebox"/>
            <input type="button" onClick="validator()" name="validation" value="Press me for validation"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`document.write()` is used to write to the document *stream*.

In your case, the stream is most probably already closed when the onClick handler is called, because your document has finished loading.

Calling `document.write()` on a closed document stream automatically calls `document.open()`, which will clear the document.

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER—No. Read the [*specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170) linked from the page you referenced: "*Open a document stream for writing. If a document exists in the target, this method clears it.*"

Answer (score 15):

A `document.write()` called after the page loads will overwrite the current document.

You want to set the text of some element within your document. If you add a

```
<p id="message"></p>
```

to the end of your body, then you can call

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "your text here";
```

Or with the jQuery library

```
$("#message").html("your text here");
```

Comment: It should be `$("body").append("your text here");`

Comment: changed some things around - setting the html of a <p> with an id instead of just appending to the body - a bit cleaner this way

Answer (score 12):

Calling `document.write` *after* the document has been loaded implicitly calls `document.open`, which clears the current document.  (Compare to calling `document.open` while the page is loading, which inserts the string into the document stream; it does not clear the document.)

`document.write` is one of the oldest vestiges of ancient JavaScript, and should generally be avoided.  Instead, you probably want to use DOM manipluation methods to update the document.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for: document.open(); Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
alert("Checkbox is checked");
```

or if you will be displaying it on page, first create an element with an id "message" (you can write anything you want, but remember, id's have to be unique on the page) like

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

and then use

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Checkbox is checked";
```

or if you are using jQuery:

```
$("#message").html("Checkbox is checked");
```

or if you are using a console enabled browser (Firefox, Chrome etc.)

```
console.log("Checkbox is checked");
```

instead of

```
document.write("Checkbox is checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var x = document.createElement("div")
        document.body.appendChild(x)
```

Comment: I Fixed It! Fixed Document.write!

Comment: I removed the `</div>` and only grabbed the lines from `var x ...` to `x.innerHTML ...`, and I found this worked in my application. (I had to add semicolons, too.)

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` is not best way to go as if there is any, yes ANY, DOM manipulation happening or happened already then `document.write()` does not work very well as it modifies original document but ignores any changes to DOM tree.

Also remember that browser displays things primarily from DOM, not from original document.