# JavaScript line break issue

Tags: javascript, setinterval

In this snippet, when `'FirstText'` is written, then rest of first line is skipped. Then `'SecText'` is written on the 2nd line:

```
<pre>
 <script>
  function text(){
  document.write("FirstText \n SecText");
  }
  text();
 </script>
</pre>
```

But when I use `setInterval()` on this function, words are written next to each other (lines are not skipped).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need another \n after SecText?

Comment: you need a <br> : `document.write("FirstText <br /> SecText");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're seeing `\n` create a new line because you're inside a `<pre />` tag; normally you have to use a `<br />` to see a similar new line outside of `<pre />`.

When you call `document.write` before the page has finished loaded, the output is entered inplace; so you'll see your `FirstText \n SecText` written within the `<pre />`.

However, when it's called *after* the page has loaded (within `setInterval`), the existing page is cleared *before* the result is written; hence `<pre />` is being removed, and you're not seeing your new line any more.

As you're not closing the `document` using `document.close()`, successive calls to `document.write` in your `setInterval` are adding to the document stream opened by the *first* iteration of `setInterval`.

You can fix this by using a `<br />` rather than `\n`;

```
     <script>
      function text(){
      document.write("FirstText <br /> SecText <br />");
      }

      setInterval(text, 1000);
     </script>
```

For more info, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write and [document.write clears page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873942/document-write-clears-page)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
document.write("FirstText <br /> SecText <br/>");
```

working example:

http://jsbin.com/oyolod/4/