# Loading openx banners via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, openx

I would like to load a banner that I know was created with openx, the code of the banner however, contains document.write commands meaning it clears the page when run out of an iframe ([document.write clears page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873942/document-write-clears-page)) and because my banner is expandable, I wanna load it into a div

Here's the banner's code:

```
<!--/* OpenX Javascript Tag v2.8.8 */-->    
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--//<![CDATA[     
var m3_u =    (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://www.aw04.net/ads/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://www.aw04.net/ads/www/delivery/ajs.php');     
var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);     if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';     
document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);     
document.write ("?zoneid=299");     
document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);     
if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);     
document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));     
document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));     
if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));     
if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));     
if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");     
document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");  *///]]>-->
</script>
<noscript>
<a href='http://www.aw04.net/ads/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a47d7715&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'>
<img src='http://www.aw04.net/ads/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=299&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=a47d7715' border='0' alt='' />
</a></noscript>
```

Is there a way of loading this script unmodified to something not an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overwrote the document.write with the following code:

```
var elementToWrite = null;

document.write = function () {
    if (elementToWrite != null) {
        elementToWrite.append([].concat.apply([], arguments).join(''));
    }
};
```

Now I just have to set the elementToWrite variable with some element from jQuery, this actually broke a few things but nothing I can't fix from application code

Answer (score 0):

All you need - it's two links (link to `<image src=""` attribute and link for `<a href=""` attribute).

So you can get it on your back-end server and returns it as json, for example