# Using document.write removes all other text and displays only the message

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just have a question about how I would make it so that there is a button in one column and when you click the button, text appears in another column. My overall goal is to make a simple clicker.

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Clicker</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 11.6" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width=600>
            <tr>
                <td width=300><span><font size=24px><button onclick='onClick()'>
                    click me
                    </button></span></td>
                <td sidth=300><span><font size=24px>So does this</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <script>
        clicks = 0;

            function onClick () {
                clicks = (clicks + 1);
                document.write ("you have clicked the button ")
                document.write (clicks)
                document.write (" times")
            };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have what I need to make it so that you get a message when you click the button, but when I do, all the other text dissipears and I get just that message. Tell me if it was a really stupid mistake or not please. I need to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.write clears page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873942/document-write-clears-page)

Comment: If you’re using a tutorial that teaches you to use `<font>` and `document.write`, _leave that tutorial immediately_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the count of clicks in the page, and keep your html, a simple way to achieve that is adding a `div` and manipulate only its content with `getElementById` (to get the element) and then call `innerHTML` (to change the content of an HTML element).

Add this bellow your html table:

```
<div>
  <h1 id=click-event> </h1>   
</div>
```

And change your `onClick()`:

```
function onClick () {
  clicks = (clicks + 1);
  document.getElementById("click-event").innerHTML = "you have clicked the button " + clicks + " times";
};
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH MY FRIEND!

Comment: My mistake was really dumb.

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

With peace and love for a confusing question.

```html
<button onclick="a='textContent';t[a]=t[a].replace(/\d+/,++this[a])">0</button><p id=t>Total:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an annonymous function when you click the button and call the `counting()` function. This will increase the value of the variable `countingClicks` and then set the `innerText` of the element in the other column to that variable.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("counter");
var y = document.getElementById("display");
var countingClicks = 0;

function counting() { 
  countingClicks++;
  y.innerText ="Number of times clicked: " + countingClicks;
}

//When the counter button is clicked call counting
x.onclick = function(){
 counting()
}
```

```css
.container{
  width: 600px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.six{
  width: 48.33%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="six">
      <button id="counter">Counter</button>
    </div>
    <div class="six">
      <span id="display"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```