# How to "go back" after document.write?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript. Currently I am learning about buttons, alerts and writing documents. For a fun little side project, I want to press a button and then it writes to a document. That works great, but I have other buttons to press but I do not know how to "go back" to the other page and push those other buttons. How can I maybe make a button to "go back" or user a timer? Which would be easier? Once I am on that other page, I don't want to stay there.

Example:

```js
function myTest1() {
     document.write("JavaScript")
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="myTest1()" value="What language is this?">
```

Comment: When you say 'go back', what do you mean?

Comment: don't use document.write, instead just `document.body.textContent = "JavaScript";` that way you can modify the content in various ways.

Comment: Ideally, I have a few more buttons than "What language is this" but once the "document.write" happens, my screen just shows "JavaScript". How can I get back to the screen with the other buttons on it?

Comment: consider adding an element on the page with an ID. <div id="myContent"></div>. Then write the content to that div instead. document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML = 'JavaScript'; Then to "go back" you just empty the contents of that element. document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML = '';

Comment: I would append text to an element instead of using `document.write` that way you won't [clear the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873942/document-write-clears-page)

Comment: When you do a `document.write` the page gets destroyed (replaced with what you wrote). There is no going back.

Comment: [Don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice). Consider following a newer tutorial if you want to learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By keeping the buttons in a container and the displayed "page" in another:

```js
function myTest1() {
     // document.getElementBy('content') id to get the content element
     // set innerHTML to change the content
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "JavaScript";
}

function goBack() {
     // document.getElementBy('content') id to get the content element
     // set innerHTML to change the content
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "Click a button to change this content";
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
    <input id="which-language-btn" type="button" onclick="myTest1()" value="What language is this?">
    <input id="bo-back-btn" type="button" onclick="goBack()" value="Go back" />
</div>
<div id="content" style="border: 1px solid;">
    Click a button to change this content
</div>
```

Or by changing both buttons and content:

```js
function myTest1() {
     // document.getElementBy('content') id to get the container element
     // set innerHTML to change the content
     document.getElementById('button-container').innerHTML = "JavaScript<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"goBack()\" value=\"Go back\" />";
}

function goBack() {
     // document.getElementBy('button-container') id to get the container element
     // set innerHTML to change the content
     document.getElementById('button-container').innerHTML = "Click a button to change this content<input id=\"which-language-btn\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"myTest1()\" value=\"What language is this?\">";
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
    Click a button to change this content<input id="which-language-btn" type="button" onclick="myTest1()" value="What language is this?">
</div>
```

The idea is using innerHTML instead of document.write too avoid replacing all your document (including your script)

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` [clears the document when it's called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document.

You *could* just keep appending the output to the body, but it's much better in the long run to adjust the content of a separate div, used for output, rather than just keep adjusting the body.

```js
function myTest1() {
     document.getElementById('output').textContent += "JavaScript\n"
}
```

```css
#output {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 30);
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  padding: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="myTest1()" value="What language is this?">
<div id="output">

</div>
```