# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I got error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` for below script.
I added the script tags after the body. But still I get the error.
I want to show the text boxes in the same page within the div with the ID `showTextBoxes`.

Below is the HTML and JS.

```js
function showArray(){
  var numofArr = document.getElementById("numofArr").value;
  for (let i = 0; i < numofArr; i++) {
    var a = document.writeln('<input type="text" name="Fname"><br/><br/>');
    document.getElementById('showTextBoxes').innerHTML = a;
  }
  document.writeln('<input type="submit" name="submit">');
}
```

```html
<p>Number of arrays(array within 0-9)</p>
<input type="text" id="numofArr" pattern="[0-9]">
<input type="submit" onclick="showArray()" value="Submit"><br><br>
<div id="showTextBoxes"></div>
```

Comment: You can't use `document.writeln` like that.

Comment: how should i correct this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append data to div using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Actually `document.write()`and `document.writeln()` works in a different ways you think. 
It actually clears all the `document` in your case you you are getting `null`.
**[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873942/document-write-clears-page)**
If you wanna add some element to your body you can use `document.body.innerHTML += string`.`appendChild()` can also be used but its not for `stings`

```js
function showArray(){
      var numofArr = parseInt(document.getElementById("numofArr").value);
           for (let i = 0; i < numofArr; i++) {
            var a = '<input type="text" name="Fname" /><br/><br/>'
            document.getElementById('showTextBoxes').innerHTML += a;
          }
      document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>'
}
```

```html
<body>
   <p>Number of arrays(array within 0-9)</p>
   <input type="text" id="numofArr" pattern="[0-9]">
<input type="submit" onclick="showArray()" value="Submit"><br><br>

 <div id="showTextBoxes"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several ways, but I would recommend looking at append. Something like this should work:

```
function showArray(){
      var numofArr = document.getElementById("numofArr").value;
           for (let i = 0; i < numofArr; i++) {
              var textBox = document.createElement("input");
              var enter = document.createElement("br");
              document.getElementById('showTextBoxes').append( textBox );
              document.getElementById('showTextBoxes').append( enter );
          }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various places in your script which prevent it from running correctly. I'll address them step by step so you can follow along.

First of all, you *should* avoid inline event handlers in your HTML for the same reasons you should avoid inline style declarations. So don't use `onclick=" ... "` inside your HTML and instead add eventlisteners in your JS. This also gives you the ability to *cancel the default behaviour* or *stop event propagation* and such things.

Next thing is, you try to use the `value` of your `numofArr` input as upper bounds for your loop without casting it to a `Number`. Because `<input>` elements return their value as a `String`, this is very likely to fail. Besides, you *should* use the `type="number"` attribute instead of `type="text"` on that element. It's not *required* to do so, but just good measure.

OK, now for the `showArray` function:
Instead of using `document.writeln` (or `document.write`), create elements with `document.createElement` and add them to the DOM with `appendChild`.

You can see a working example below. Don't be confused by the `byId` and `makeEl` functions, they are just utilities so you don't have to write `document.getElementById` and `document.createElement` all the time.

```js
// ====== UTILITY FUNCTIONS ======
function byId (id, root = document) {
  return root.getElementById(id);
}

function makeEl (tag) {
  return document.createElement(tag);
}


// ====== PROGRAM STUFF ======
function showArray (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let numofArr = parseInt(byId('numofArr').value, 10);
  let output = byId('showTextBoxes');

  for (let i = 0; i < numofArr; i++) {
    let textIn = makeEl('input');
    textIn.type = 'text';
    textIn.name = 'Fname';
    
    output.appendChild(textIn);
    output.appendChild(makeEl('br'));
    output.appendChild(makeEl('br'));
  }

  let submit2 = makeEl('input');
  submit2.type = 'submit';
  submit2.value = 'Submit';
  document.body.appendChild(submit2);
}

byId('submit1').addEventListener('click', showArray, false);
```

```html
<p>Number of arrays(array within 0-9)</p>
<input type="number" id="numofArr">
<input id="submit1" type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
<div id="showTextBoxes"></div>
```