# Parse ipstack JSON Data using JS

Tags: javascript, json

I was working on how to extract data from JSON data

I wrote the below code to extract the variable named code that is equal to ur

But not getting the results.

```
<script>
var txt = '{ "type":"ipv4", "location":{ "geoname_id":2816, "languages":[ { "code":"en", "name":"English" }, { "code":"ur", "name":"Urdu" } ], "is_eu":false } }';
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
console.log(obj.location.languages.code);
</script>
```

Comment: it works. Maybe you cant see result. Try with console.log()

Comment: Its not working bro, want to get code from the json data.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.  This is working correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.write clears page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873942/document-write-clears-page)

Comment: Your `languages` is an Array, you have to use an index to access it first and then the prop name like `code` for example `obj.location.languages[0].code`

Answer (score 1):

`obj.location.languages` is an Array, you cannot access `code` property be requesting it directly on it. `code` property of which item it should give you back after all, one of English or Urdu? You will need to use an index of the item (starts with 0) to access it, or use one of the iterator methods on the Array, like `forEach()`, `map()` or `reduce()` to cycle trhough all of them. Here's an example:

```js
var txt = '{ "type":"ipv4", "location":{ "geoname_id":2816, "languages":[ { "code":"en", "name":"English" }, { "code":"ur", "name":"Urdu" } ], "is_eu":false } }';
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);

var html = '';
obj.location.languages.forEach(function(lang) {
  html += '<li>' + lang.name + ' (' + lang.code + ')</li>';
});

document.getElementById('languages').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
Languages: <br />
<ul id="languages"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use index after languages propert. Because this propert type is array.

```
<script>
var txt = '{ "type":"ipv4", "location":{ "geoname_id":2816, "languages":[ { "code":"en", "name":"English" }, { "code":"ur", "name":"Urdu" } ], "is_eu":false } }';
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
document.write(obj.location.languages[0].code);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`languages` is an array, so try something like that:

```
obj.location.languages[0].code
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will get you all language code as an array.

```
<script>
var txt = '{ "type":"ipv4", "location":{ "geoname_id":2816, "languages":[ {"code":"en", "name":"English" }, { "code":"ur", "name":"Urdu" } ], "is_eu":false } }';
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
document.write(obj.location.languages.map((language,i)=>language.code));
</script>
```