# Automatic year with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem I want to change the Automatic year with javascript
as in php is this possible?

document.write (new Date (). getFullYear ()); this works but want to plug that into var, but then page is completely off just a year this and screen shot [enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8OA8.png

$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready copyright" );

```
        var copyright = 'Copyright&copy;';
        var static_year = 2014;
        var test = document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
        var company ="Hondenverzorgingleentje";
        var company_url = 'https://www.hondenverzorgingleentje.be';
      
        document.getElementById("copyright").innerHTML = copyright + 
        static_year + company + copyright;


    }
```

Copyright©'.$static_year.' - ' .$current_year.' ' .$company.' Alle rechten voorbehouden  ' .$designer.''; ?>

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Perhaps you could update the question to include a runnable code snippet which fully demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Please review [ask] and [the help center article on how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Echoing @David, you can create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  using something like [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: @DylanLandry Or [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>`) right here on Stack Overflow...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: who taught you to us document.write for a variable? `var test = new Date().getFullYear(); console.log(test);`

Comment: Welcome!
Please edit your code to show code quote/snippet = it spilled...
Also, add `jquery` tag and/or any other library you might be using.
It's best if you use a snippet here and not codepen/other third-party links.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add all strings using template literals instead of using plus to concat strings.

So, try this with the dynamic year:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `Copyright&copy; ${new Date().getFullYear()} Hondenverzorgingleentje ${designer}`;
```

You are probably getting blank page because of the Document.write() call.
Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873942/document-write-clears-page) for the details on why it may clear the page.

If you want to have a clickable company name, define company and company_url variables, and then you can use this code

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `Copyright&copy; ${new Date().getFullYear()} <a href="${company_url}">${company}</a> ${designer}`
```

Comment: okay but could the company have a link

Comment: @PcNerd yes, the company can have a link. Just wrap it inside an A element with the link.

Comment: you can do that from a variable var = 'company'; var company_url = 'https://www.test.be' and mention it in document.getElementById ("demo"). innerHTML =

Comment: Yes, absolutely you can do that. Make sure your company_url variable starts with http:// or https. I edited my answer with the suggested code that includes company name with the link.

Comment: this in a javascript please <?php $static_year = '2018'; $current_year = date('Y'); $company = 'Hondenverzorgingleentje'; $company_url = ('hondenverzorgingleentje.be'); $designer = 'test'; $designer_url = 'test.be'; echo '<div id="copyright"><span>Copyright&copy;'.$static_year.' - ' .$current_year.' <a href=' .$company_url. ' title='.$company.' class="company">' .$company.'</a> Alle rechten voorbehouden&nbsp; <a href=' .$designer_url. ' title='.$designer.' class="company">' .$designer.'</a></div>'; ?>

Comment: Check this codepen please: https://codepen.io/ozgursar/pen/qBNpzjo

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer, or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: thank you very much and can you also add span id copyricht and urls so you can style them

Comment: In the codepen link, I added classes to the company and designer links. You can now target them in css by #copyright .company {} and #copyright .designer selectors.

Comment: I have tried but this does not work

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What didn't work? I updated the codepen example once more to include custom styling with the casses. Please take a look: https://codepen.io/ozgursar/pen/qBNpzjo

Comment: ok thanks a lot, i'm also trying the same for the days when you case
is open and closed

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display the current year on your webpage.

If I were you I would create a HTML id/class to access it via js and update the content when the page loads.

If you only need to set the year at one place you can use this:

```html
<p>Copyright 1234-<span id="current-year"></span></p>
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
```

```js
// script.js
document.getElementById('current-year').innerText = new Date().getFullYear()
```

If you need to display it at multiple locations you need to use html classes.

```html
<p>Copyright 1234-<span class="current-year"></span></p>
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
```

```js
// script.js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('current-year'))
  .forEach(el => el.innerText = (new Date()).getFullYear())
```

Notes:
the defer attr. in the script tag will block the execution of the javascript until your html dom is loaded.

getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object and not an array, so I converted it into an array and used array#forEach. I could have used a regular for loop on the array-like object but I prefer this oneliner.

Comment: this in a javascript please <?php $static_year = '2018'; $current_year = date('Y'); $company = 'Hondenverzorgingleentje'; $company_url = ('hondenverzorgingleentje.be'); $designer = 'test'; $designer_url = 'test.be'; echo '<div id="copyright"><span>Copyright&copy;'.$static_year.' - ' .$current_year.' <a href=' .$company_url. ' title='.$company.' class="company">' .$company.'</a> Alle rechten voorbehouden&nbsp; <a href=' .$designer_url. ' title='.$designer.' class="company">' .$designer.'</a></div>'; ?>