# Document.write is not working properly with media queries. What can I do - or is there an alternative?

Tags: javascript, document.write

This little function gives me a headache.

`document.write` in combination with media queries just won't work responsive.

I'm trying to change the css stylesheet with `document.write` as soon as the `max-width` changes.

It works, but not responsive - I have to reload the page.

It works perfectly fine with `document.body.style.backgroundColor` as example - but not with `document.write`.

Does anyone know why, or is there a better way?

```
let Swidth = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
  function reSize(Swidth) {
    if (Swidth.matches) {
      /* document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; // This works */
      document.write('<link href="./src/css/variant1.css" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet">');

    } else {
      
      /* document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; // This works */
      document.write('<link href="./src/css/variant2.css" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet">')

    }
  }
reSize(Swidth);
Swidth.addEventListener("change", reSize);
```

Comment: It's not the media queries, it's [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), which clears the page when called after the page has been parsed. See [how to modify an existing document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Document.write clears page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873942/document-write-clears-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `media` attribute of the `<link>` element.

```html
<link href="./src/css/variant1.css" type="text/css" 
      rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 700px)">
<link href="./src/css/variant2.css" type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet" media="not screen and (max-width: 700px)">
```

Answer (score -2):

This solution works for me.

```
function addStylesheet(theHref) {
    if (document.createStyleSheet) {
        document.createStyleSheet(theHref);
    } else {
        var newSheet = document.createElement('link');
        newSheet.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        newSheet.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        newSheet.setAttribute('href', theHref);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newSheet);
    }
}

let Swidth = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")

function reSize(Swidth) {
    if (Swidth.matches) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        addStylesheet("./src/css/variant1.css")
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        addStylesheet("./src/css/variant2.css")
    }
}
reSize(Swidth);
Swidth.addEventListener("change", reSize);
```